# Export all files from a folder in es module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, esmodules

I have the following script which is attempted at exporting every single file from a particular folder, but I'm stucked at the export part of it.

Below is what I've attempted:

**index.js**

```
function exportAllFiles() {
    fs.readdir(filesDir, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        files.forEach(async file => {
            const module = await import(file);
            //'export module.default' ;export statement is not working for me here, how can I make it work here?
        });
    })
}

exportAllFiles();
```

After importing each file as seen above I have no idea how to export it as the export statement doesn't seem to work for me in that block.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you put this code into "index.js" then it'll pick up any other JS modules in that directory and expose them as sub-modules.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync('./dir/path').forEach(function(file){
    if ( file.indexOf(".js") > -1 && file != "index.js" ) 
        exports[ file.replace('.js','') ] = require('./'+file);
});
```

Be sure to replace `./dir/path` with the `path` of the directory.

[Source](https://gist.github.com/richmarr/1122217/578a2767ec126b9b9526b6ac6df7d9935ee190d8)